# Apps for NCERT Books

Tags: software-recommendation, ebooks, directory-structure

Is any desktop application available for NCERT books? There is the availability of windows application. Structured (subject wise, topic wise) downloaded books also preferred. Android Emulator is an option but not best.

Comment: Which NCERT books are you referring to? NCERT Class I to Class XII books?

Comment: What does `file` say about a book?

Comment: @technastic_tc, I am looking for Class I to Class XII all subjects.

Comment: @waltinator Didn't get you.

Comment: @Posi2 Are you referring to the Epathshala app?

Comment: @technastic_tc yes

Comment: @Posi2 The Epathshala app is only there for Windows, Apple and Android. There's no official support for Linux.  But you can use the Epathshala website in Linux. Check this link: http://epathshala.nic.in/process.php?id=students&type=eTextbooks&ln=en